# How to get html paragraph value to a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, echo, getelementbyid, messagebox

I'm trying to use a PHP conform box to get user approved before delete a data. Therefore I used this below code to display the conform box and it's working fine.

But now I'm having troubles with retrieving user response. For now it's assigned to a paragraph (called demo) but I want it to assign to a php variable ($user_res). I have no idea how to do this.

```
 <?php

  echo '<p id="demo" ></p>';
    echo '<script>';
     echo 'var txt;';
     echo ' var r = confirm("Press a button!");';
     echo 'if (r == true) {';
     echo 'txt = "You pressed OK!";';
     echo '} else {';
     echo 'txt = "You pressed Cancel!";';
     echo '}';
     echo 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;';
    echo '</script>';

   ?>
```

Comment: You can't assign it to a PHP variable client-side - but you could assign the value to an HTML input and then POST it, or you could POST it to a PHP script using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML in your PHP file and insert php tags for $key processing.

```
<html>
<?php $key="demo" ?>
    <p id="demo" ></p>
 <script>;
     var txt;
     var r = confirm("Press a button!");
     if (r == true) {
     txt = "You pressed OK!";
     } else {
     txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
     }
     document.getElementById("<?php $key ?>").innerHTML = txt;
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.
I found this and It's also working.

<button id="btnfun1" name="btnfun1" onClick='location.href="?button1=1"' >OK</button>
    <button id="btnfun2" name="btnfun2" onClick='location.href="?button2=1"' >Cancel</button>

if($_GET['button1']){fun1();}
 if($_GET['button2']){fun2();}
 
 function fun1()
 {
   echo "fun1";
 }
 function fun2()
 {
   echo "fun 2";
 }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anurag. That was helpful.
I found this and It's also working.

```
 <button id="btnfun1" name="btnfun1" onClick='location.href="?button1=1"' >OK</button>
        <button id="btnfun2" name="btnfun2" onClick='location.href="?button2=1"' >Cancel</button>

 <?php
   if($_GET['button1']){fun1();}
     if($_GET['button2']){fun2();}

     function fun1()
     {
       echo "fun1";
     }
     function fun2()
     {
       echo "fun 2";
     }
```